# Unable to exit try-catch block used for a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, try-catch, joptionpane

I made a try-catch block to make sure the input I get from a JOptionPane is correct, but I am unable to exit out of the program when I click cancel or close on the JOptionPane, as I am stuck in the while loop.

```
     while(value)
     {
     try
     {
        players = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to start a two-player(enter 2) or three-player(enter 3) game?"));
        value = false;
        if(players != 2 && players != 3)
           throw new InputMismatchException();

     }

     catch(InputMismatchException e)
     {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a valid input.");
        value = true;

     }

     catch(NumberFormatException f)
     {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a valid input.");
        value = true;

     }

     if(players == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION || players == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION)
        value = false;

     }
```

Any tips for exiting the program?

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception when you could simply loop?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a combo box in the option pane to allow the user to choose the number of players?

Then you know the data will always be valid and you just need to handle the Yes/No buttons.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) for an example of this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution for you. Please let me know if you need help with anything.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Status {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean value = true;
    int players = 0;
    String input;
    while (value) {

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to start a two-player(enter 2) or three-player(enter 3) game?");

        //exits the loop if the user closes the window or presses cancel
        if (input == null)
            break;

        //if a user doesn't enter a number display error message
        try {
            players = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a valid input.");
        }

        //if a user enters an invalid number display error message
        if (players != 2 && players != 3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a valid input.");
        } else {
            value = false;
        }


    }
  }
}
```